# Generate java classes from xsd using intelliJ

Tags: java, xml, intellij-idea, xsd

Im trying to use IntelliJ to create java classes from some xml - the steps im doing is following :

1. Save xml from a specified partner url through a browser
2. Use IntelliJ to generate XSD schema from XML file
3. Use IntelliJ to generate java classes from xsd file

My problem is that the only thing that happens is that it creates the specified package and copies the xsd to this package - no java classes is made.

The xml im downloading looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<oxip version="7.1" created="2014-12-08 15:23:34" lastMsgId="" requestTime="0.1790">
<response request="getPools" code="001" message="success" debug="" provider="GENERIC">
<disclaimer>
</disclaimer>
<pool id="1081" name="Auto Pool-2014-12-02 09:00:00" poolType="TF12" poolTypeId="12" jackpot="N" provider="Internal" fracBetsAvail="Y" quickPicksAvail="Y" reduceSysAvail="Y" displayOrder="" typeDisplayOrder="1" subsAvail="N" maxSubs="3" numPicks="12" currency="DKK" url="" lastUpdateDate="2014-12-01" lastUpdateTime="09:00:19" opensAt="2014-12-02 09:00:00" closesAt="2014-12-08 20:00:00">
<poolLink id="1082" relationship="child" type="H1"/>
<poolPrizes>
<prize numCorrect="10" winners="0" guarantee="0" value="11.70" size="11.7"/>
<prize numCorrect="11" winners="0" guarantee="0" value="35.10" size="35.1"/>
<prize numCorrect="12" winners="0" guarantee="0" value="70.20" size="70.2"/>
</poolPrizes>
<event id="16382" classId="97" typeId="13304" typeName="Premijer Liga" displayOrder="0" displayed="Y" name="Blackpool v Bordeaux" url="/e/16382" date="2014-12-09" time="22:00:00" betTillDate="2014-12-09" betTillTime="22:00:00" suspend="" status="A" channels="IMR" country="" flags="FE" raceNumber="" lastUpdateDate="2014-12-01" lastUpdateTime="09:00:10">
</event>
<event id="16383" classId="97" typeId="13304" typeName="Premijer Liga" displayOrder="0" displayed="Y" name="Clydebank v Ayr United" url="/e/16383" date="2014-12-09" time="22:10:00" betTillDate="2014-12-09" betTillTime="22:10:00" suspend="" status="A" channels="IMR" country="" flags="FE" raceNumber="" lastUpdateDate="2014-12-01" lastUpdateTime="09:00:16">
</event>
<event id="16384" classId="97" typeId="13304" typeName="Premijer Liga" displayOrder="0" displayed="Y" name="Barcelona v Bournemouth" url="/e/16384" date="2014-12-09" time="22:20:00" betTillDate="2014-12-09" betTillTime="22:20:00" suspend="" status="A" channels="IMR" country="" flags="FE" raceNumber="" lastUpdateDate="2014-12-01" lastUpdateTime="09:00:16">
</event>
<event id="16385" classId="97" typeId="13304" typeName="Premijer Liga" displayOrder="0" displayed="Y" name="Derby v Bristol Rovers" url="/e/16385" date="2014-12-09" time="22:30:00" betTillDate="2014-12-09" betTillTime="22:30:00" suspend="" status="A" channels="IMR" country="" flags="FE" raceNumber="" lastUpdateDate="2014-12-01" lastUpdateTime="09:00:16">
</event>
<event id="16386" classId="97" typeId="13304" typeName="Premijer Liga" displayOrder="0" displayed="Y" name="Crystal Palace v Clyde" url="/e/16386" date="2014-12-09" time="22:40:00" betTillDate="2014-12-09" betTillTime="22:40:00" suspend="" status="A" channels="IMR" country="" flags="FE" raceNumber="" lastUpdateDate="2014-12-01" lastUpdateTime="09:00:17">
</event>
<event id="16387" classId="97" typeId="13304" typeName="Premijer Liga" displayOrder="0" displayed="Y" name="Blackpool v Darlington" url="/e/16387" date="2014-12-09" time="22:50:00" betTillDate="2014-12-09" betTillTime="22:50:00" suspend="" status="A" channels="IMR" country="" flags="FE" raceNumber="" lastUpdateDate="2014-12-01" lastUpdateTime="09:00:18">
</event>
<event id="16388" classId="97" typeId="13304" typeName="Premijer Liga" displayOrder="0" displayed="Y" name="Cambridge v Arbroath" url="/e/16388" date="2014-12-09" time="23:00:00" betTillDate="2014-12-09" betTillTime="23:00:00" suspend="" status="A" channels="IMR" country="" flags="FE" raceNumber="" lastUpdateDate="2014-12-01" lastUpdateTime="09:00:18">
</event>
<event id="16389" classId="97" typeId="13304" typeName="Premijer Liga" displayOrder="0" displayed="Y" name="Clydebank v Aston Villa" url="/e/16389" date="2014-12-09" time="23:10:00" betTillDate="2014-12-09" betTillTime="23:10:00" suspend="" status="A" channels="IMR" country="" flags="FE" raceNumber="" lastUpdateDate="2014-12-01" lastUpdateTime="09:00:18">
</event>
<event id="16390" classId="97" typeId="13304" typeName="Premijer Liga" displayOrder="0" displayed="Y" name="Belgien v Cheltenham" url="/e/16390" date="2014-12-09" time="23:20:00" betTillDate="2014-12-09" betTillTime="23:20:00" suspend="" status="A" channels="IMR" country="" flags="FE" raceNumber="" lastUpdateDate="2014-12-01" lastUpdateTime="09:00:18">
</event>
<event id="16391" classId="97" typeId="13304" typeName="Premijer Liga" displayOrder="0" displayed="Y" name="Bournemouth v Coventry" url="/e/16391" date="2014-12-09" time="23:30:00" betTillDate="2014-12-09" betTillTime="23:30:00" suspend="" status="A" channels="IMR" country="" flags="FE" raceNumber="" lastUpdateDate="2014-12-01" lastUpdateTime="09:00:18">
</event>
<event id="16392" classId="97" typeId="13304" typeName="Premijer Liga" displayOrder="0" displayed="Y" name="Deportivo v Chester" url="/e/16392" date="2014-12-09" time="23:40:00" betTillDate="2014-12-09" betTillTime="23:40:00" suspend="" status="A" channels="IMR" country="" flags="FE" raceNumber="" lastUpdateDate="2014-12-01" lastUpdateTime="09:00:18">
</event>
<event id="16393" classId="97" typeId="13304" typeName="Premijer Liga" displayOrder="0" displayed="Y" name="Chesterfield v Aberdeen" url="/e/16393" date="2014-12-09" time="23:50:00" betTillDate="2014-12-09" betTillTime="23:50:00" suspend="" status="A" channels="IMR" country="" flags="FE" raceNumber="" lastUpdateDate="2014-12-01" lastUpdateTime="09:00:18">
</event>
</pool>
</response>
</oxip>
```

and the xsd looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="oxip" type="oxipType"/>
  <xs:complexType name="oxipType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="responseType" name="response"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:float" name="version"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="created"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="lastMsgId"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:float" name="requestTime"/>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="poolType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="poolLinkType" name="poolLink"/>
      <xs:element type="poolPrizesType" name="poolPrizes"/>
      <xs:element type="eventType" name="event" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:short" name="id"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="name"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="poolType"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="poolTypeId"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="jackpot"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="provider"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="fracBetsAvail"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="quickPicksAvail"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="reduceSysAvail"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="displayOrder"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="typeDisplayOrder"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="subsAvail"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="maxSubs"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="numPicks"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="currency"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="url"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:date" name="lastUpdateDate"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:time" name="lastUpdateTime"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="opensAt"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="closesAt"/>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="poolPrizesType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="prizeType" name="prize" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="responseType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="disclaimer"/>
      <xs:element type="poolType" name="pool"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="request"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="code"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="message"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="debug"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="provider"/>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="poolLinkType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute type="xs:short" name="id"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="relationship"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="type"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="eventType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute type="xs:short" name="id" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="classId" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:short" name="typeId" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="typeName" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="displayOrder" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="displayed" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="name" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="url" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:date" name="date" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:time" name="time" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:date" name="betTillDate" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:time" name="betTillTime" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="suspend" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="status" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="channels" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="country" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="flags" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="raceNumber" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:date" name="lastUpdateDate" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:time" name="lastUpdateTime" use="optional"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="prizeType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="numCorrect" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="winners" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="guarantee" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:float" name="value" use="optional"/>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:float" name="size" use="optional"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Can somebody explain to me why im not able to generate java classes from the above ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because of the following line in the xsd

```
<xs:attribute type="xs:float" name="value" use="optional"/>
```

since value is already defined in 'datatypes.jar' somewhere

Comment: What is 'datatypes.jar'. I'm encountering the same error with completely different xsd/xml.

Comment: I dont remember where the datatypes.jar came from. But in my case the 
name="value" was illegal because similar was defined in another jar file included in jaxb